# run commands in android

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-support-library

I was reading about support libraries and it suggested this way to find out
which dependencies i'm using in my android project:
BUT  how to and where to run commands?

"If you want to see what libraries and library dependencies are included in your app, run the following command at the build root of your app development project to get a report of the dependencies for that project"

Comment: command prompt?

Comment: Open a terminal or command prompt. Use `cd` command to go to your project folder. You can run your command there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
 gradle app:dependencies
```

in terminal.

if you are using Windows:

```
     gradlew app:dependencies
```

Comment: I ran this command in android studio's terminal and it says i have to install the gradle (sudo apt install gradle) BUT I have the gradle installed in my software. what now?

Comment: Maybe you have to install gradle by your own.

Comment: Download gradle's file and extract It and copy all files and paste it under:  C:\Users\{USERNAME}\.gradle\wrapper\dists\